# Why not plug DeAuth

Tags: wifi

They way I understand DeAuth-ing a user on a wireless network is this: The attacker pretends to the AP he is the user and to the user he is the AP. He then tells the AP (as a user) "I need to re-authenticate!" and the user (as the AP) "You need to re-authenticate!" So why aren't networks set up by default so that only the AP can decide if and when a user re-authenticates? It seems to me that this is a rather obvious solution, so I would assume I am missing something -- anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 1):

The deauth and auth  packets aren't encrypted so once you get the BSSID and the MAC address of the client and the AP you can spoof the packet. The reason you wouldn't want to have those packets encrypted is if you've lost your connectivity due to a changed encryption key, your wifi interface wouldn't be able to send any legible traffic to the AP to tell it what was up. The AP would just be like, "Hey man, my key doesn't decode that traffic into anything I can understand so I'm just going to drop these packets over here, k?" It's a pretty similar situation when you're authenticating for the first time. Although the more I think about the authentication frame being non-encrypted the more I think that is a flaw with the 802.11 standard (but I could also be slightly misinterpreting the auth phase).

This answer over [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12410/35888) helped me get a better understanding of it. The link to [Wi-fi Planet](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/1447501) in there also has some stuff to help me get my head around it.

Comment: why not encrypt with a PSK unique to each router? the AP could send out a notification to all connected users if it changed.